# Add Primary Key constraint automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table InfoSchema which contains the SchemaName and the TableName of each table in my test database :

```
SchemaName TableName
dbo        Employee
dbo        Department
Function   Company
Finance    Payslips
Sub        ProjectSub
```

I want to add for each table the constraint PrimaryKey to the column ending with ID or Id :
In dbo.Employee there is one column EmployeeId so the query will be like below :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ADD CONSTRAINT Employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId);
```

For Sub.ProjectSub there are 3 columns ending with Id :

- ProjectId
- CompanyId
- SubId

The constraint will be added at the first column appearing in the structure of the table.

Comment: You *could* do this with Dynamic SQL, and scan the tables in the database, however, I admit that I **strongly** recommend against this, and if you *do* go down this path I ***very* strong** suggest you check over the SQL it produces first. But for 5 tables, just write the SQL yourself.

Comment: if you're creating the table though, why not include teh PK's definition in the `CREATE`script?

Comment: @larn I may be lazy a little bit but the table are already created as I am not charged of the staging task.

Comment: Then you just need to write 5 `ALTER` statements. That will be far quicker than writing a dynamic statement.

Comment: @Larnu it's about 100+ tables

Comment: Will is *always* be the first column (ordinally) with the `id` suffix that needs to be the PK, Sandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, you can use a dynamic statement to create the statements. I ***very* strongly** suggest looking over the SQL generated, however, so I do not include an `EXEC sp_executesql` statement here. `PRINT` or `SELECT` the value of `@SQL` and check it over first, then run the statements as you need:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + @CRLF +
                         N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF +
                         N'ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(t.[name],N'_PK')) + N' PRIMARY KEY (' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N');'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                                      AND c.name LIKE '%id'
                                    ORDER BY c.column_id ASC) c
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                   FROM sys.key_constraints k
                                   WHERE k.[type] = 'PK'
                                     AND k.parent_object_id = t.object_id)
                 FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,4,N'');

PRINT @SQL;
```

This *assumes* that the first column, ordinally, needs to be the PK, and it will not attempt to create a PK on  a table that already has one.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. There is no automatism for this in SQL Server, so it will require at least a script to run over the db to identify tables and columns and issue modify statements. Which is not "automatic" as it will not RUN automatic - you need to run it in a second step.